# Find #ID, AddClass by URL in Navigation Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I am making a website. I want to go from link to next page with ID. Like the following

**Page Name:** index.html

```
<a href="collection.html#rings">Rings</a>
```

**Page Name:** collection.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">

<li id="rings" class="active"><a href="#">Rings</a></li>
<li id="earrings"><a href="#">Earrings</a></li>
<li id="neckwears"><a href="#" id="test1">Neckwear</a></li>
<li id="purses"><a href="#">Purses</a></li>
<li id="mini"><a href="#">Set an mini set</a></li>
</ul>
```

I try to take code and implement in this but not get any success.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {

       $(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    var url = window.location.hash;
    $('#nav li').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
    });
</script>
```

I wan to put active class automatically in #nav list via using URL # value.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the pathname as a selector, like this: `$('#nav li#'+current)`

There is no reason to loop through all of them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(function() {
    var current = "rings"; //location.pathname
    $('#nav li#' + current).addClass("active");

  });
});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">

  <li id="rings" class=""><a href="#">Rings</a></li>
  <li id="earrings"><a href="#">Earrings</a></li>
  <li id="neckwears"><a href="#" id="test1">Neckwear</a></li>
  <li id="purses"><a href="#">Purses</a></li>
  <li id="mini"><a href="#">Set an mini set</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not working. even not showing any error.  why you write +current here?

Answer (score 0):

You were just comparing to the wrong variable. Just change your code to the below

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    var url = window.location.hash;
    $('#nav li').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if("#" + $this.attr('id') == url){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    });
  });
});
```